# Meizu MX4 touchscreen problems

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

The touchscreen of my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition is not working correctly.
Until today the screen sometimes did its own thing. moving around and opening all kind of apps. But today the middle part of the screen is not responding anymore, top and bottom works fine. It looks to me this is a hardware issue, but could it be software?

Martin

Answer (score 0):

it looks a bit odd. Are you sure nothing is interfering with the screen? (phone cover, etc?). Have you noticed problems with the phone temperature?
The middle part of the screen would include the keyboard? Can you try using the keyboard both in portrait and landscape mode to check the screen? 
I've heard of other people having problems with their screens but we couldn't track it to a software problem yet.

Comment: No nothing is interfering. It has no case or screenprotector. the is getting hot when playing videos, but not in standby mode. When you go to the dialpad for example, 1 2 3 7 8 9 and 0 are working, but 4 5 and 6 won't respond. So its the complete horizontal line. when I turn my phone to landscape mode it becomes a vertical line that won't work.